# Thrust: sort_by_key slow due to memory allocation

Tags: sorting, slowdown, thrust

I am doing a `sort_by_key` with key-value int arrays of size 80 million.
The device is a **GTX 560 Ti** with **2GB** VRAM. When the available (free)
memory before the sort_by_key is `1200MB`, it finishes sorting in `200ms`.
But, when the available memory drops to `600MB`, the sort_by_key for the
same key-value arrays takes `1.5-3s`!

I ran the program under **Compute Visual Profiler**. I found that the GPU
timestamp jumps by 1.5-3s between the last kernel before `sort_by_key`
and the first kernel call inside `sort_by_key` (which is a
`RakingReduction`).

I suspect there is a memory allocation being done inside `sort_by_key`,
before it calls its first internal kernel. The memory that `sort_by_key`
needs is available (even when available memory is `600MB`) since the
`sort_by_key` works, even though it is slower. I see that the computer
freezes for 1s when this happens. I also see a bump in the CPU
**Physical Memory** graph if I keep **Process Explorer** open.

Is there anything I can do to make this `sort_by_key` work just as fast
when available memory is lesser? Also, what is happening between the
device and host that is causing the memory bump and temporary
freezing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thrust::sort_by_key indeed allocates temporary space of O(N) -- radix sort is not an in-place sort when it is larger than can be done by a single multiprocessor.  Therefore you need at least 80M * 2 * sizeof(int) = 640MB for the input data, plus space for the temporaries, which must be at least 320MB for this sort.  I'm not sure exactly why the sort doesn't just fail when you don't have enough memory -- perhaps 600 MB is a low estimate, or perhaps thrust is falling back to CPU execution (I doubt it does that).

Another idea about the performance drop is that when you need *almost* all of the available memory, there might be a bit of fragmentation in the available memory that the driver/runtime has to deal with in order to allocate such large arrays, causing extra overhead.

BTW, how are you measuring available memory?

Comment: harrism: Thanks! I measure available memory using cudaMemGetInfo(). I am pretty sure Thrust is NOT falling back on CPU. But, according to Jared Hoberock (NVIDIA) this might be due to problems with CUDA drivers on Windows: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/thrust-users/nXQD6j7_xfs