# cuda array sorting with thrust, not enough memory

Tags: c++, arrays, cuda, gpu, thrust

I'm trying to sort an array using Thrust, but it doesn't work if the  array is too big. (I have a GTX460 1GB memory)

I'm using cuda with c++ integration on VS2012, Here is my code :

my .cpp

```
extern "C" void thrust_sort(uint32_t *data, int n);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int n = 2<<26;
    uint32_t * v = new uint32_t[n];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        v[i] = rand()%n;
    }

    thrust_sort(v, n);

    delete [] v;
    return 0;
}
```

my .cu

```
extern "C"
void thrust_sort(uint32_t *data, int n){
    thrust::device_vector<uint32_t> d_data(data, data + n);
    thrust::stable_sort(d_data.begin(), d_data.end());
    thrust::copy(d_data.begin(), d_data.end(), data);
}
```

The program stop working at the start of stable_sort().

---

1. How much more memory does stable_sort() need ?
2. Is there a way to fix this ? (even if it makes it a bit slower or whatever)
3. Is there another sorting algorithm that doesn't require more memory than the original array ?

---

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: thrust sorting [requires O(N) temporary space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605498/thrust-sort-by-key-slow-due-to-memory-allocation).  So when you've used up about half of the GPU memory with storage for your array to be sorted, you'll run out of space.  I don't know of a way around this.  I've played a bit with [back40 sort](http://code.google.com/p/back40computing/wiki/RadixSorting) and [MGPU sort](http://www.moderngpu.com/sort/mgpusort.html), and both require additional storage, although I haven't benchmarked how much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are in the literature some techniques used to deal with the problem of sorting data that is too big to fit in `RAM`, such as saving partial values in files, and so on. An example: [Sorting a million 32-bit integers in 2MB of RAM using Python](http://neopythonic.blogspot.pt/2008/10/sorting-million-32-bit-integers-in-2mb.html)

Your problem is less complicated since your input fits in `RAM` but is too *much* for your GPU. You can solve this problem by using the strategy `parallel by Regular Sampling`. You can see [here](http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/ifi/INF3380/v10/undervisningsmateriale/inf3380-week12.pdf) an example of this technique applied to `quicksort`.

Long story short, you divide the array into smaller sub-arrays that fit on the memory of the GPU. Then you sort each of the sub-arrays, and in the end, you merge the results base on the premises of the Regular Sampling approach.

You can use a hybrid approach, sorting some of the sub-arrays in the CPU by assigning each one to a different core (using multi-threading), and at the same time, sending others sub-arrays to the GPU. You can even subdivide this work also to different processors using a message passing interface such as `MPI`. Or you can simply sort each sub-array one-by-one on the GPU and do the final merge step using the CPU, taking (or not) advantage of the multi-cores.